Accepting JSON Requests in Spring Boot 3 Regardless of Content-Type
I am currently developing an API using Spring Boot 3 with a POST endpoint that utilizes @RequestBody to receive requests. @RequestBody only processes requests with the Content-Type set to application/json.
I would like to configure my API to accept and process JSON data regardless of the Content-Type header. This means that even if the Content-Type is missing or set to something else (e.g., text/plain or application/x-www-form-urlencoded), I want to parse the request body as JSON into my RequestDto.
What would be the best approach to achieve this functionality in Spring Boot?
To achieve this, I attempted to replace @RequestBody with HttpServletRequest in my controller and manually convert the request body using ObjectMapper:
@PostMapping("/api")
public ResponseEntity<?> handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    RequestDto dto = objectMapper.readValue(request.getInputStream(), RequestDto.class);
    // Proceed with processing
}

However, this approach has drawbacks:
Validation Issues: I lose the ability to use the validation annotations (@Valid, @NotNull, etc.) that I have defined in my RequestDto. Implementing validation manually in the controller would complicate the code.
Next, I tried using a filter to override the Content-Type header in incoming requests, hoping that Spring would process the request body as JSON regardless of the original Content-Type. Here's the code I used in my filter:
public class ContentTypeOverrideFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequestWrapper servletRequestWrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(
                (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest) {
            @Override
            public String getContentType() {
                return MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;
            }
        };

        chain.doFilter(servletRequestWrapper, servletResponse);
    }
}


This solution works when the Content-Type header is absent in the request. However, when the request has a Content-Type specified, the override does not take effect, and the request is not processed as JSON.
Question:

How can I configure my Spring Boot application to process JSON data in POST requests regardless of the Content-Type header, while still utilizing the validation annotations in my RequestDto?
Is there a way to globally override or ignore the Content-Type header for specific endpoints or for the entire application, so that all request bodies are treated as JSON?
Alternatively, is there a better approach to achieve this functionality without losing the benefits of @RequestBody and validation annotations?


You can try creating custom message converter with public class CustomMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Object> and register it in configuration class this way you can still use validation and requestBody

I'm interested in the why? The content type is there for a reason if there is a mismatch it can lead to interesting results or even security issues if yo ujust deserialize everything. For the request wrapper appraoch to work you would also need to override the headers and (re)set the Content-Type header (or just override the headers and leave the original getContentType in-tact.
